# Java - Method from another class not being called even if it was called from an instance of that class

Tags: java

I'm really lost here. I'm having two classes that are involved with this issue. The first class is the `Application` class and the second one is the `GameManager` class. The `GameManager` class has a method called `instantiate()` on it that I want to call from the `Application` class.

So I created an instance of the `GameManager` class inside the `Application` class. I called the `instantiate()` method from **THAT VERY INSTANCE**, but nothing happens.

It was supposed to output `"Instantiating GameObject"` to the console, but it doesn't happen. Not even once. What's even more confusing is the `renderGame()` method in the `GameManager` class **DOES** get called(and for testing purposes I had it output the amount of `gameobjects` that the `GameManager` holds).

Here are the two classes:

Application class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Application implements Runnable {
    public static boolean isRunning;

    GameManager manager = new GameManager();//CREATE AN INSTANCE OF THE GAME MANAGER

    JFrame frame;
    BufferStrategy buffer;
    Graphics drawer;

    Thread appThread;

    public Application (JFrame frame, BufferStrategy buffer, Graphics drawer) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.drawer = drawer;
    }

    public synchronized void startLoop () {
        appThread = new Thread (this);
        appThread.start();
        isRunning = true;
        GameLoop ();
    }

    public synchronized void endLoop () {
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            appThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void GameLoop() {
        int targetFps = 60;
        double timePerTick = 1000000000 / targetFps;
        double delta = 0;
        long now;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(isRunning) {//THIS IS A LOOP THAT REPEATEDLY CALLS UPDATE AND RENDER METHODS
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1) {
                masterUpdate();
                masterRender();
                delta--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("STOPPED");
    }

    void masterUpdate () {
        manager.updateGame();
    }

    void masterRender () {
        manager.renderGame(drawer);//THIS IS WHERE THE RENDER METHOD IS CALLED
        buffer.show();
        drawer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startLoop();
        manager.instantiate();
    }
}
```

The GameManager class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GameManager {

    public static int currentGameObjectAmount = 0;
    public static int maxGameObjects = 100;
    Player[] sceneObjects = new Player[maxGameObjects];

    public void instantiate () {
        System.out.println("Instantiating GameObject");
        sceneObjects[currentGameObjectAmount] = new Player(100, 100, 100);
        currentGameObjectAmount++;
    }

    public void updateGame () {

    }

    public void renderGame (Graphics drawer) {
        System.out.println(currentGameObjectAmount);
        for(int i = 0; i != maxGameObjects; i++) {
            sceneObjects[i].render(drawer);
        }
    }
}
```

The console outputs `0` when it should be outputting `1` since I called the `instantiate()` method which increments the integer variable that the console is pushing out. [What happens when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yehw7.png)

PS: Sorry if my code makes your head hurt, I'm not really an advanced programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is here...

```
@Override
public void run() {
    startLoop();
    manager.instantiate();
}
```

When you call `startLoop`, this blocks the current `Thread` until `isRunning` is `false`

I would suggest moving `manager.instantiate()` above `startLoop()`. I might also consider having a `start` and `end` method some kind instead which can be used to tell the manager that the `Thread` has started or stopped, but that's just me ;)

Comment: This is just _one_ of many problems in the overall design... This would take a lot of work to untangle.

Comment: @JimGarrison Well, that's the one that will solve the immediate problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, @MadProgrammer! The instantiate method gets called now. I get a NullPointerException but I'll just figure that out on my own. Also @Jim Garrison, can you give me any ideas on what I should do to improve this?